# Select the 100 lowest values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been looking around for a while, and it seems it cant be found anywhere. I want to know how do you select the 100 highest and the 100 lowst values in a column? The MIN-function only chooses the lowest one and the MAX the highest one.

Anyone out there who knows how you do this?

Comment: mysql or sql-server? And what you want to happen with ties?

Comment: SQL-Server 2008 r2, I just want to get the 100 lowest values in a column, then I will order them by desc.

Comment: Regarding @ypercube's comment about ties, see the ranking functions in SQL Server, particularly the `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` functions as these give you control over what happens in a tie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL Server

- Top 100 Highest

  ```
  SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY MyCol DESC
  ```
- Top 100 Lowest

  ```
  SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY MyCol ASC
  ```

MySQL

- Top 100 Highest

  ```
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY MyCol DESC LIMIT 100
  ```
- Top 100 Lowest

  ```
  SELECT * FROM MyTable
  ORDER BY MyCol ASC  LIMIT 100
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as below,

**Highest**

```
select * from
tablename
order by
column DESC
limit 0,100
```

**Lowest**

```
select * from
tablename
order by
column ASC
limit 0,100
```

**EDIT**

For SQL Server replace `select * from` with `select TOP 100 * from`

The `SELECT TOP` clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

Comment: SQL Server does not support the `LIMIT` clause

Answer (score 1):

Use sorting in ascending and descending order and limit output to 100

Answer (score 1):

if you use Sql server 
you can order query desc and select top 1000 like :

```
select top(1000) * from mytable order by value desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @V_MaxNo INT; 
SELECT @V_MaxNo = COUNT(1) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (CONDITION_PART_AS_REQUIRED); 
SELECT COLUMN_LIST
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Order_by_column_list_with_ASC/DESC]) rowNo, COLUMN_LIST 
      FROM TABLE_NAME) A 
WHERE (100 - rowNo) >= 0 or (@V_MaxNo - rowNo) < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach independent from db engine

MAX

```
select * from MyTable a where 100 > (select count(id) from MyTable b where a.MyCol <= b.MyCol) order by MyCol desc
```